# TypeError: fit_transform() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have pandas DataFrame `df`. I want to encode continuous and categorical features of `df` using different encoders. I find it very comfortable to use `make_column_transformer`, but the code shown below fails with `LabelEncoder()`, but works fine with `OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))`. The error message is:

> TypeError: fit_transform() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were
>   given

It's not clear to me how to fix this issue.

The code:

```
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler, OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder

continuous_features = ['COL1','COL2']       
categorical_features = ['COL3','COL4']

column_trans = make_column_transformer(
    (categorical_features,LabelEncoder()),
    (continuous_features, RobustScaler()))

X_enc = column_trans.fit_transform(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer.html.

```
make_column_transformer(
...     (StandardScaler(), ['numerical_column']),
...     (OneHotEncoder(), ['categorical_column']))
```

So for your case:

```
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler, OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder

continuous_features = ['COL1','COL2']       
categorical_features = ['COL3','COL4']

column_trans = make_column_transformer(
    (OneHotEncoder(), categorical_features),
    (RobustScaler(), continuous_features))

X_enc = column_trans.fit_transform(df)
```

If you want to use `LabelEncoder()`, you can only pass one column, not two!

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Fluxy, can you post your data? Just first few rows.

Comment: It's a huge data set. Do you have any assumption why this can happen?

Comment: @Fluxy, can paste the column names?

Comment: I have the same output of `column_trans`, but when I do `column_trans.fit_transform(df)`, it fails.

Comment: I am pasting categorical column names, because these are the ones that give a problem.

Comment: `LabelEncoder()` only allows one column and you put two!

Comment: Ok, thanks. But you also put 2 in your answer, or did I miss something?

Comment: What is the workaround in this case? Thanks for finding the cause.

Comment: @Fluxy, I didn't have the data, so I didn't do the `fit_stransform()` step.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like LabelEncoder cannot be used… It's unrealistic that there is only 1 categorical variable in a data set. There should be some workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Imo the problem here was that `LabelEncoder` could not (and still can't) be used within `ColumnTransformer`s or `Pipeline`s instances, because it is meant to only transform targets, while `ColumnTransformer`s and `Pipeline`s are intended to be used for feature transformation only.

This can be clearly seen from the signatures of methods `.fit()`, `.transform()`, `.fit_transform()` of the [`LabelEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) class, which differ from the ones of "more-standard" transformers.

> fit(y) vs fit(X[,y]) | transform(y) vs transform(X) | fit_transform(y) vs fit_transform(X[,y])
>
> respectively for *LabelEncoder-like* transformers (i.e. transformers to be applied on target) and for transformers to be applied on features.

I've just posted an answer in full details at [Why should LabelEncoder from sklearn be used only for the target variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62892086/why-should-labelencoder-from-sklearn-be-used-only-for-the-target-variable/70923020#70923020).

This said, *if* using `LabelEncoder` within a `ColumnTransformer` was allowed, you would have probably incurred in a problem described in the other answer and deriving from the fact that the input to `LabelEncoder` should be 1D (and btw in such cases both the `ColumnTransformer` constructor and the `make_column_transformer` method would have required the `columns` parameter to be passed as a *string* rather than as a *list of string(s)*). A common use case for this can be seen in the usage of instances of classes meant to deal with texts, like `CountVectorizer`, which do require 1D inputs
(see [Sklearn custom transformers with pipeline: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70550018/sklearn-custom-transformers-with-pipeline-all-the-input-array-dimensions-for-th/70550548#70550548), for instance).

Eventually, from sklearn version 0.20, an alternative to the `LabelEncoder` that can be used on feature vectors is the `OrdinalEncoder`.